# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strlen() in /home/oursite/public_html/wp-content/themes/effektive/functions/layout-objects.php on line 495

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am getting an error here at following link :

error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strlen() in /home/oursite/public_html/wp-content/themes/effektive/functions/layout-objects.php on line 495
```

http://webngraphicssolutions.com/?page_id=707

please can any one tell me..what is it?

please don't give me negative votes..don't need that..i am new here..

also layout-objects.php file is following at pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/psRj9SGm

Comment: no one replied it..please i need help..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419102/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-strlen

Comment: thank you my friend..chris herbert

Comment: you really saved my time...

Answer (score 1):

It Can't Find the File ( mb_strlen() ) in your whole DATA you stored in your project. Find out this function where this function is implemented in your project.