# How to extract random substring from a string in php?

Tags: php

I would like to extract random substrings form a string, how could I do this?

Let's say I have this string as one word:

`$string = "myawesomestring";`

and as an output I want an random response like this with extracted substrings

`myaweso myawe somestr`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the length of the string, and, of course a random number.

```php
function getRandomSubstring($text) {
  $random1 = rand(0, mb_strlen($text));
  $random2 = rand($random1, mb_strlen($text));
  return substr($text, $random1, $random2);
}
```

Comment: I fixed a typo in there. Your function can return an empty string though, which probably isn't wanted.

Comment: This works - OP may want to run this in a loop to match their desired output (multiple instances on the same line). Also worth noting not everyone may have mb_strlen available (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6419126/3080207).

Comment: Sometimes it shows a blank response but basically, it works. Thank you!

Comment: @user2534787 That's what I meant by my first comment. Use `mb_strlen($text) - 1` instead on the first line to prevent it.

Comment: i try this code but it's not work proper 
   _____________________<?php
  echo $string = 'myawesomestring'; 
  function getRandomSubstring($text) {
    $random1 = rand(0, mb_strlen($text));
    $random2 = rand($random1, mb_strlen($text));
    return substr($text, $random1, $random2);
  }
  $output_data = getRandomSubstring($string);
  echo $output_data;
?>_____________output_data in value not found blank data given.

Comment: There is no regular distribution here. You have more chance to have end characters appearing than beginning characters. To have regular distribution, you need to roll the both randoms from 0 to maximum length. Then keep the lowest at second argument for `substr` and use the absolute substract of the two values for the third argument for `substr`

Answer (score -2):

**Try this code:**

```
<?php
      $str = "myawesomestring";
      $l = strlen($str);
      $i = 0;                                 
      while ($i < $l) {
          $r = rand(1, $l - $i);              
          $chunks[] = substr($str, $i, $r);   
          $i += $r;                           
      }
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($chunks); 
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does this snippet use random substrings?

Comment: Can you explain what that code does? When I execute it, it shows only a pretty limited amount of substrings, and they never share the same letters in the front (like in the example in the question)